# How to properly display records by product id in PHP

Tags: php

The query below displays all products from database, and it's working fine.

```
$sql_query .= "SELECT * FROM my_products ";
if(strip_tags(isset($_POST["search"]["value"]))){

$search_value= strip_tags($_POST["search"]["value"]);
$sql_query .= 'WHERE  first_name LIKE "%'.$search_value.'%" ';
$sql_query .= 'OR last_name LIKE "%'.$search_value.'%" ';
$sql_query .= 'OR product_name LIKE "%'. $search_value.'%" ';
  }



//ensure that order post is set
$start = $_POST['start'];
$length = $_POST['length'];
$draw= $_POST["draw"];
if(strip_tags(isset($_POST["order"]))){
$order_column = strip_tags($_POST['order']['0']['column']);
$order_dir = strip_tags($_POST['order']['0']['dir']);

$sql_query .= 'ORDER BY '.$order_column.' '.$order_dir.' ';
}
else{
$sql_query .= 'ORDER BY id DESC ';
}
if($length != -1){
$sql_query .= 'LIMIT ' . $start . ', ' . $length;
}

$pstmt = $db->prepare($sql_query);
$pstmt->execute();
$rows_count = $pstmt->rowCount();


while($row = $pstmt->fetch()){
$rows1 = array();

$id = $row['id'];
$fname = $row['first_name'];
$lname = $row['last_name'];
}
```

Here is my issue: I want to display the products records where product id is 100.

I have tried code below but it's still showing all the record. What can I try next?

```
$product_id= '100';

$sql_query .= 'WHERE product_id ="'.$product_id.'" AND  first_name LIKE "%'.$search_value.'%" ';
$sql_query .= 'OR last_name LIKE "%'.$search_value.'%" ';
$sql_query .= 'OR product_name LIKE "%'. $search_value.'%" ';
```

Comment: Try to Set product_id = 100; integer value. Also try only the first part of the SQL containing WHERE product_id = $product_id   and see if it works before adding LIKE section.

Comment: The security vulnerabilities in this code put you and your users at risk. Do **not** put this code into production.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Check your query and run it in database.

I think this is a bracket issue of `OR` condition. Try this:

```
$product_id= '100';

$sql_query .= 'WHERE (product_id ="'.$product_id.'" AND  first_name LIKE "%'.$search_value.'%" )';
$sql_query .= 'OR last_name LIKE "%'.$search_value.'%" ';
$sql_query .= 'OR product_name LIKE "%'. $search_value.'%" ';
```

Be aware though that there are SQL injection vulnerabilities in this code, and you must fix them in a production environment.